# dojo provide with declare

Tags: dojo

I'm trying to clear something up that I'm not getting from the dojo docs. 
When I create a dojo provide I assume this is like creating a namespace with objects. For example.

myApp = { container: {} }

Written in dojo provide would be:

dojo.provide('myApp.container');

Now I have read somewhere where this is a global. Not sure I get that as its a namespace or are people true in saying this.

Another issue I'm having is if I use a declare to create a class do I need to use provide to create that namespace for me. for example

```
myClass.js file

dojo.provide('myApp.myClass');

dojo.declare("myApp.myClass", null, {

  constructor: function(){
    console.log("myApp.myClass created");
  }

});
```

Now if there is truth to provide causing global variables then would this not be a global class now.
When I do a console.log from my app.js file which is my main.js file its not showing as a global but in fact as namespace myApp.myClass.

So can someone clear this up as its a little strange if there is truth in it.

Comment: Well, there are no "namespaces" in JavaScript.  Namespaces are "faked" by global variable chains.  That's why you are confused.

Comment: `dojo.provide` creates the entire chain of the namespace objects, ensuring that a parent level is always defined beforing creating the child level.  In your example, the minimum you have to do is `dojo.provide("myApp")`, otherwise when you `dojo.declare` myApp.myClass, myApp will be undefined and it will be an error.  If you `dojo.provide("myApp.myClass")`, then myApp will have a property myClass which is initially an empty object.  Then your `dojo.declare` call overwrites that empty object.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, to clarify the term "global", technically `myApp` is a global - it is a variable on the browser's `window` object.  While yes, ultimately the object/class your module defines is contained within that global object (and thus "namespaced" under it), that top level namespace itself manifests as a global variable; it is accessible to any script in the page/app.

Now, onto the declare question.  Assuming this code is going into its own module to be loaded via `dojo.require`, yes, you still need the `dojo.provide`.  While one purpose of `dojo.provide` is to ensure the variable you will be populating (e.g. `myApp.MyClass`) and any parent namespaces exist up-front, its other purpose is basically to act like an ACK to `dojo.require`'s SYN - i.e., "yes, you asked for `myApp.MyClass`, and that's who I am."  I'm pretty sure you would find that in the absence of that `dojo.provide`, `dojo.require("myApp.MyClass")` would fail, thinking it never found the module it was looking for.

Hope that answers your questions.